# Ternary Operator As Boolean Cast

Tags: c++

Is there any reason why the following two expressions would not be equivalent?

- **(expression) ? true : false**
- **(bool) (expression)**

Comment: There's another one: `!!expression`

Comment: I consider `expr ? true : false` an anti-pattern. Don’t use it. Use implicit conversion – or, if you absolutely must, explicit conversion. But in the same vein, don’t use C-style casts, they’re trouble and most people strongly discourage their usage. Use a `static_cast`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph make that an answer and you'd get +1! Your comment is much more useful than the current answer, anyway...

Comment: @KonradRudolph but that is not as enterprisey as `bool isTrue(bool val);`. [Think of the possibilities!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Test-of-Truth.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No, those two expressions are the same.  `expression` is evaluated once in both cases, and the whole expression type is `bool` in both cases.